# C++: adress of variable returned? How do I get this string to return, and then concat a small string onto it?

Tags: c++

function:

```
//http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/
char* get_current_time()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer [80];  //main.cpp:73: warning: address of local variable ‘buffer’ returned

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

    strftime (buffer,80,"%Y %m-%d %H-%M-%S",timeinfo);
    puts (buffer);
    return buffer;
}
```

which is invoked by:

```
char* filename = get_current_time();
filename = strcat(filename, ".txt");
```

and the puts outputs to the console:

```
2011 03-18 13-51-59
```

so... for the most part the function works...

but when I     `puts (filename);` after the strcat, I get this:

```
p??_
```

Comment: really, you couldn't find any information on returning a string from a function, using either SO search or google?

Comment: this is not c++, it is c (and there's a really big difference, as noted in the first answer posted)

Comment: Changing the tag made most answers inappropriate.  Since the OP asked about C++, let's teach how to convert this C-like code to good C++, not specify how to do it in C.

Comment: @aschepler - I disagree - there is not the first attempt at writing c++ here (besides naming the program main.cpp).  No std::string, using puts (and not cout) are all examples of NOT using c++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning a LOCAL address is a bad bad bad idea.

In C++, `std::string` solves most of such issues. Prefer using it.

Also, forget about `strcat`, and use `+` or/and `+=` with `std::string`.

Re-writing your code:

```
std::string get_current_time()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer [80]; 

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

    strftime (buffer,80,"%Y %m-%d %H-%M-%S",timeinfo);
    puts (buffer);
    return buffer; //it converts into std::string automatically!
}

std::string filename = get_current_time();
filename += ".txt"; //concatenate. Compare it with strcat!
```

It looks better now.

Answer (score 2):

Heed the warning. `buffer` is a contiguous area of memory allocated **on the stack**. Once the call stack unwinds (your function returns), local storage is rendered garbage.

If you want to return a pointer to a memory that survives the return of the function, allocate said memory in the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Your buffer is allocated in stack and is abandoned after you leave the function. The most you can do here is make it static, that will just make your function non-reentrant.

Better yet pass the buffer allocated in the caller function to the get time thingie.

And, as Nawaz suggests, since you're in c++ you may want to use `std::string` class instead if you don't want to learn how strings/memory/etc. work (you'll have to, anyway, though;-)).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with c instead of using c++ strings, this is the best way to do it

```
void get_current_time(char *buffer, int max_len)
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

    strftime (buffer, max_len,"%Y %m-%d %H-%M-%S",timeinfo);
}
```

Then call it like this

```
char buffer[80];
get_current_time( buffer, 80 );
buffer = strncat(filename, ".txt", (80 - (strlen(buffer)+1)));
```

This will make sure you don't overrun your buffer size when writing and concatenating your strings